# XSLT: how can I filter out all elements with a specific namespace

Tags: java, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<zoo xmlns="http://myurl.com/wsdl/myservice">
  <animal>elephant</animal>
  <exhibit>
    <animal>walrus</animal>
    <animal>sea otter</animal>
    <trainer xmlns="http://example.com/abc">Jack</trainer>
  </exhibit>
  <exhibit xmlns="http://example.com/abc">
    <animal>lion</animal>
    <animal>tiger</animal>
  </exhibit>
</zoo>
```

How can I write an XSLT stylesheet that filters out all elements and/or all node trees in the "http://example.com/abc" namespace?

Desired result XML:

```
<zoo xmlns="http://myurl.com/wsdl/myservice">
  <animal>elephant</animal>
  <exhibit>
    <animal>walrus</animal>
    <animal>sea otter</animal>
  </exhibit>
</zoo>
```

I'm trying something like this, but it just isn't working:

Failed XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://example.com/abc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Update

I got a good suggestion, but it's still not working. Here's the Java code I'm using to do the XSLT translation:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*; // XML DOM
import javax.xml.parsers.*; // DocumentBuilder, etc
import javax.xml.transform.*; // Transformer, etc
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*; // StreamResult, StreamSource, etc
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().testZoo();
    }

    public void testZoo () {
System.out.println ("Reading zoo.xml");     
        String zooXml = MassageXfddXml.readXmlFile ("zoo.xml");
        if (zooXml == null)
            return;
        
        try {
            // Read XFDD input string into DOM
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder ();
            Document xfddDoc = 
                docBuilder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream (zooXml));
        
            // Filter out all elements in "http://example.com/abc" namespace
            StreamSource styleSource = new StreamSource (new File ("zoo.xsl"));
            Transformer transformer =
                TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer (styleSource);
        
            // Convert final DOM back to String
            StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter ();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,  "yes"); // Remember: we want to insert this XML as a subnode
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,  "yes");
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xfddDoc), new StreamResult (buffer));
            String translatedXml = buffer.toString();
System.out.println ("initial XML:\n" + zooXml + "\nfinal XML:\n" + translatedXml);          
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("convertTransactionData error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
```

Here's the new stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://example.com/abc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:* | @a:*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's the output:

```
Reading zoo.xml
bytes read=337
initial XML:
<zoo xmlns="http://myurl.com/wsdl/myservice">
  <animal>elephant</animal>
  <exhibit>
    <animal>walrus</animal>
    <animal>sea otter</animal>
    <trainer xmlns="http://example.com/abc">Jack</trainer>
  </exhibit>
  <exhibit xmlns="http://example.com/abc">
    <animal>lion</animal>
    <animal>tiger</animal>
  </exhibit>
</zoo>

final XML:
<zoo xmlns="http://myurl.com/wsdl/myservice">
  <animal>elephant</animal>
  <exhibit>
    <animal>walrus</animal>
    <animal>sea otter</animal>
    <trainer xmlns="http://example.com/abc">Jack</trainer>
  </exhibit>
  <exhibit xmlns="http://example.com/abc">
    <animal>lion</animal>
    <animal>tiger</animal>
  </exhibit>
</zoo>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://example.com/abc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:* | @a:*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Empty templates match nodes but do not output anything, effectively removing what they match.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, it's still not working for me.  Perhaps the problem is my Java (vs. my XSL)?  I've updated my question with the code above.

Comment: @paulsm4 It's not the XSLT. Look at http://www.xmlplayground.com/tuCNmf - It's the same code (albeit XSLT v1.0, but that does not matter in this case) and it does what you want. Maybe you have a typo in your namespace?

Comment: @paulsm4 this suggested XSLT is correct but for what I can only assume are backwards compatibility reasons, `DocumentBuilderFactory` produces _non-namespace-aware_ document builders by default. You need to call `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the DBF before you call `newDocumentBuilder()` to make the parser namespace-aware.

Comment: @IanRoberts WTF are "non-namespace-aware document builders"? I can't imagine a single good reason to create an XML handling facility that clobbers namespaces. What were they thinking?!

Comment: @Tomalak a parser that doesn't do namespaces - `<foo:bar>` is just an element whose name happens to contain a colon, and `xmlns="..."` is a normal attribute. It's occasionally useful, I've had to do non-namespace-aware parsing when dealing with documents containing elements with generated names like `<urn:example.com:something>` (which is well-formed XML but not namespace-well-formed, namespaces are a separate spec, not part of XML 1.0 itself).

Comment: @IanRoberts I can relate to reducing the namespace URI handling to "accepts any string". But entirely removing them from the parser - and by default at that - is just not a very smart thing.

Comment: @IanRoberts - beautiful!  I was trying different XSLT syntax until I was blue in the face.  Some stuff was working, most attempts were doing nothing ... and all the while, the *SOLUTION* was to "`setNamespaceAware(true)`" way, way back in the DocumentBuilderFactory!  It works now.  I've updated my original post.  Many thanks to both Tomalak (for the syntax) and Ian Roberts (for "setNamespaceAware(true)".

Comment: @paulsm4 That's StackOverflow at work. I would not have been able to help you on my own.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move the answer to the answer space)*.

Many thanks to Tomalak for the correct XSL syntax, and to Ian Roberts for pointing out that in order to use namespaces in my XSLT, I need to call "setNamespaceAware(true)" at the very beginning, in my DocumentBuilderFactory.

XSLT (thanks to Tomalak):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://example.com/abc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a:* | @a:*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java program that successfully does the XSLT filtering by namespace:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*; // XML DOM
import javax.xml.parsers.*; // DocumentBuilder, etc
import javax.xml.transform.*; // Transformer, etc
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*; // StreamResult, StreamSource, etc
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().testZoo();
    }

public void testZoo () {
    String zooXml = Test.readXmlFile ("zoo.xml");
    if (zooXml == null)
        return;
    
    try {
        // Create a new document builder factory, and make sure it[s namespace-aware 
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder ();

        // Read XFDD input string into DOM
        Document xfddDoc = 
            docBuilder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream (zooXml));
    
        // Filter out all elements in "http://example.com/abc" namespace
        StreamSource styleSource = new StreamSource (new File ("zoo.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer =
            TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer (styleSource);
    
        // Convert final DOM back to String
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter ();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,  "yes"); // Remember: we want to insert this XML as a subnode
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,  "yes");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xfddDoc), new StreamResult (buffer));
        String translatedXml = buffer.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println ("convertTransactionData error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

Comment: (Addendum for the transcription: unfortunately the editor no longer permits `foo.com` anywhere in posts, so I have updated it to use `example.com`).